# What are best resources to understand concurrency in golang?

Tags: go

I am new to go? Can someone specify resources for understanding concurrency using go?

Comment: In future, please ask these kinds of questions on the Gophers slack channel, the gobridge forum or the go-nuts irc channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The golang.org docs are great: https://golang.org/doc/

Specifically:

- [Share Memory by Communicating](https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/sharemem/)
- [Go Concurrency Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs)
- [Advanced Go Concurrency Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDDwwePbDtw)

Comment: Please don't answer these questions. They are off-topic.

Comment: Please try to keep links [local to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/info).

Comment: Linkrot? The question is off-topic? [Leading to external resources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)?

Comment: Sound's to me like it's just a sub-category of "off topic"; understood.